# Create a style file using ArcEngine?

Tags: arcgis-engine

Is it possible to create a style file to complement a shapefile using ArcEngine?

I'm using C# VS2010 ArcEngine 10.

Comment: Do you mean a layer file (which stores the symbology, definition query, and other properties you would set in the layer properties panel in ArcMap)?

Comment: @Regan Sarwas,  No I mean a style file with a .style extension see this question for more context, http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4213/control-the-colors-of-a-shapefile

Comment: you would be talking about an lyr file. A style file holds symbology.

Comment: brad is correct what you are looking for in the other post is a lyr file, see http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/2233/647 but george is correct in this post only *.serverstyle is used in AcgEngine so you need to convert a *.style file that you can create in ArcMap ta a *.serverstyle file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that this is what you looking for:

http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/NET/886d432f-77d9-4ce0-a38c-1a347d6e9be7.htm